# Change links titles of PDF uploads

Tags: 7, files

I have been trying to find a sensible solution to this problem with no success so far.

I have a site running Drupal 7 – and have built a basic content type which allows content admins to upload their own PDF documents using a file field. The content admins now what to be able to rename the PDF title that appears in the download link to whatever they want, but I can’t find a workable solution to achieve this. I have tried File (Field) Paths, but it was a disaster – full of bugs.

Is there a module out there somewhere that can allow what should be simple functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file module has that built right in. Edit the settings for your file field, and find this bit:

[image]

Save that, and go back to your node edit form where you will see:

[image]

With both the included field formatters you should see the contents of the 'Description' field for the link text of each file.

Comment: Unbelievable! Under my nose all this time. Clive – you’re a legend, thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Is it possible at all to have that field use a default value? (like the title of the content)